# android - SOAP-xml response to Java Object (Retrofit 2)

Tags: java, android, xml, model

I need to create a Java Object from the soap-xml response.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://api.myip.org/api" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns1:LoginResponse>
            <return xsi:type="xsd:string">1111222333</return>
        </ns1:LoginResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:GetHouseInfoResponse>
            <return SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:HouseInfo[1]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfHouseInfo">
                <item xsi:type="ns1:HouseInfo">
                    <house_id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</house_id>
                    <state xsi:type="ns1:HouseStateEnum">0</state>
                    <stage xsi:type="ns1:HouseStageEnum">3</stage>
                    <drifting_date xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <full_address xsi:type="ns1:FullAddress">

                       //this block is huge, but i don't need it anyway

                    </full_address>
                    <inn xsi:type="xsd:string">123</inn>
                </item>
            </return>
        </ns1:GetHouseInfoResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is my question. I need ONLY `house_id` parameter, that's it. I tried this model:

```
@Root(name = "SOAP-ENV:Envelope", strict = false)
public class XmlHouseInfoResponse {

    @Element(name = "SOAP-ENV:Body")
    public HouseInfoResponseBody responseBody;

    @Root
    public static class HouseInfoResponseBody {

        @Element(name = "ns1:GetHouseInfoResponse")
        public GetHouseInfoResponse houseInfoResponse;

        @Root
        public static class GetHouseInfoResponse {

            @Element(name = "return")
            public ReturnSectionHouseInfoResponse returnSection;

            @Root
            public static class ReturnSectionHouseInfoResponse {

                @Element(name = "item")
                public ItemSectionHouseInfoResponse itemSection;

                @Root
                public static class ItemSectionHouseInfoResponse {

                    @Element(name = "house_id")
                    private int houseId;

                    public int getHouseId() {
                        return houseId;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, I get "`Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=SOAP-ENV:Body, required=true, type=void) on field 'responseBody' public com.myproject.di.services.api.models.response.XmlHouseInfoResponse$HouseInfoResponseBody com.myproject.di.services.api.models.response.XmlHouseInfoResponse.responseBody for class com.myproject.di.services.api.models.response.XmlHouseInfoResponse at line 2`". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe you need to have the whole response modeled in the Java object.  Whatever the solution, that is not a very helpful error message.

Comment: Well, I didn't find the answer. So I tried to do full response model - still the same error.